# SVN to Git migration : issue with Git folder structure and Git Branches

Tags: git, svn, migration, branch

We are in process of migrating code from SVN to Git. We have more than 50 projects to be moved to Git.

Our project structure looks like this.

```
  SVN Repo

   Project 1
     Branches
      Tags
       Trunk

   Project 2
     Branches
      Tags
       Trunk

   Project 2
     Branches
      Tags
       Trunk

   Project 3
     Branches
      Tags
       Trunk
      .
      .
      .
    Project N
     Branches
      Tags
       Trunk
```

I am able to successfully migrate individual projects to individual git repo but i am finding difficulty in migrating all the projects to single git repository.

We are facing few problems in migration.

1. How to create multiple projects in single repository in Git?
   We tried of doing 2 SVN projects in single repo to Git but it converted in wiered way. we completely lost folder structure in migrated code. 
   but we are able to migrate single SVN project to single git repo successfully.
2. How to get the branch migrated from SVN to Git. Actually in SVN we have 2 branches DEVELOPMENT and MAINTENANCE . but actually in SVN branch folder i can see the whole lot of revision directories(ex 1.0.1 , 1.1.1, 1.2.1 ) instead of logical branch.
   How to migrate these branches to git ? will i able to get exactly 2 braches like Development or Maintenance? How can we migrate all the projects into a single git repository?

Comment: Pls explain what command or tool you are using for migration

Comment: We are using git-svn tool.

git svn clone https://svn-server-location/ C:/TEMP/gitrepo/Proj –no-metadata -A authors.txt -t tags -b branches -T trunk

This will successfully migrate code to git , but we are facing issues with migrating branches and tags.

Comment: What part of your workflow is it that keeping svn's everything-in-one-repo layout will preserve?  It may be git's got a different way to achieve that.